# Is it possible to add all images from some folder to a list or something?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example i have 100 images in the folder "Images" in my project.
thats insane to decide defining 100 times new image and add them to my list. I guess there must be easier way..

Comment: What have you tried already? What code have you written? Do you know about loops? Or maybe LINQ?

Comment: i will learn it in future for sure

Comment: Linq is something to learn NOW :) You're disabled without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a list of your image extensions:

```
public static readonly List<string> ImageExtensions = new List<string> {
   ".jpg",
   ".jpe",
   ".bmp",
   ".gif",
   ".png"
};
```

To make your image list you could iterate through folder files differentiating them according to their extension:

```
string YourDir = "Images\\";
List<Image> MyImgList = new List<Image>();
string[] images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(YourDir);
images = images.Where(F => ImageExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(F))).ToArray();

foreach (string Img in images) {
   BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
   bmp.BeginInit();
   bmp.UriSource = new Uri(Img, UriKind.Relative);
   bmp.EndInit();
   MyImgList.Add(new Image { Source = bmp });
}
```

Comment: would it make sense to use observable collection for wpf ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\images", ". jpg")
```

Comment: As I could see the question was pretty simple and therefore didn't need much explanation.

Comment: Okay... You have none. "Much" is different from "none". What does this code *do*? How does it solve his problem?

Comment: Create the Array and assign it. I'm not sure if I misunderstood his question, but doesn't he just need an array with the content of a folder?

Comment: chill out guys. it helped me cause i didnt even know about Directory class)

Comment: I wasn't asking for my benefit, I was hoping to prompt you to update your answer with some explanation and context. Sorry, I guess I didn't make that clear.

Comment: I've posted this answer from my mobile phone. And as the answer seemed easy, I've saved myself the hassle of writing too much. Couldn't even find the code tag.